# Почему не работает скролл элемента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

Работаю с  [данной компонентой](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/detailslist). Все отрисовывается хорошо, выделение итемов работает,но почему-то нет скролла.Выводится только 21 итем и все.Хотя если регулировать высоту блока,то видно.что в массиве 500 итемов.В чем может быть ошибка?

```
export default class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if (_items.length === 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                _items.push({
                    key: i,
                    name: 'Item ' + i,
                    value: i
                });
            }
        }
        this._selection = new Selection({
            onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
        });

        this.state = {
            items: _items,
            selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails()
        };
    }

    render(){

        let {
            items,
            selectionDetails
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                    <MarqueeSelection selection={ this._selection } style={{'overflow':'auto'}}>
                        <DetailsList
                            items={ items }
                            columns={ _columns }
                            setKey='set'
                            layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
                            selection={ this._selection }
                            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={ true }
                            onItemInvoked={ (item) => alert(`Item invoked: ${item.name}`) }
                        />
                    </MarqueeSelection>
                </div>
        );
    }

    _getSelectionDetails = () => {
        let selectionCount = this._selection.getSelectedCount();
        switch (selectionCount) {
            case 0:
                return 'No items selected';
            default:
                return `${selectionCount} items selected`;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ваш код рабочий и прокрутка работает.
Чтобы его запустить, я добавил `const _items = []` и убрал `columns={ _columns }`

Comment: А еще непонятно зачем Вы `style={{'overflow':'auto'}}` передаете в `MarqueeSelection`? Его надо передавать в `div`. И `overflow` необязательно брать в одинарные кавычки.

Comment: {{'overflow':'auto'}} как раз думал передать,чтобы появился скролл. но не учел,что его надо подбросить повыше в обертку-див. если сделать так,то скролл появляется. большое спасибо. вы не могли бы продублировать комментарий в ответ?я его выберу и закрою вопрос. и еще один вопрос небольшой. как можно в данном случае раелизовать подгрузку по кокнертному числу итемов?например я хчоу,чтобы отображалось 50,или 100 и при скролле подгружалось тоже 50\100 итемов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Чтобы была прокрутка надо `style={{'overflow':'auto'}}` передать в `div`, а не в `MarqueeSelection`

2) По поводу динамической подгрузки айтемов:

Первое, что нам нужно сделать - это передать в `div` обработчик `onScroll` и получить ссылку на его node с помощью `ref`:

```
<div
   onScroll={this.handleScroll}
   ref={el => this.scroll = el}>
```

Далее получим ссылку на сам список и закешируем его высоту:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.detailList=this.scroll.childNodes[0];
    this.scrollHeight = this.scroll.clientHeight
}
```

Теперь нам надо получить предельное значение `scrollTop` по достижению которого мы будем подгружать айтемы. Первое, что скорее всего прийдет в голову - это получать его в `componentDidUpdate`, но это ошибочное решение, т.к. `DetailsList` - это ассинхронный компонент и сразу после того как наш компонент примонтируется, там айтемов не будет и его высота будет 0. Поэтому воспользуемся `onDidUpdate` самого `DetailsList`. Стоит заметить, что вызывается он не только при апдейте, но и при первом рендере айтемов.

```
<DetailsList
   onDidUpdate={this.handleDetailListUpdate}
```

И сам обработчик:

```
handleDetailListUpdate=()=>{
    this.maxScrollTop=this.detailList.clientHeight-this.scrollHeight-100;
}
```

Ну и наконец-то обработчик скролла:

```
handleScroll=()=>{
    if (this.scroll.scrollTop>this.maxScrollTop){
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat(this.getItems()),
        });
    }
}
```

Функция `getItems()` для теста:

```
startNum = 0;

getItems(){
    const items = [];
    const finishNum = this.startNum + 50;
    for (let i = this.startNum; i<finishNum; i++) {
        items.push({
            key: i,
            name: 'Item ' + i,
            value: i
        });
    }
    this.startNum += 50;
    return items;
}
```

Ну и не забудем получить первую порцию айтемов в конструкторе:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: this.getItems(),
        selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails()
    };
}
```

Вот и все.

Ну и на всякий случай код всего компонента:

```
export default class Example extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._selection = new Selection({
        onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
    });

    this.state = {
        items: this.getItems(),
        selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails()
    };
}

startNum = 0;

getItems(){
    const items = [];
    const finishNum = this.startNum + 50;
    for (let i = this.startNum; i<finishNum; i++) {
        items.push({
            key: i,
            name: 'Item ' + i,
            value: i
        });
    }
    this.startNum += 50;
    return items;
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.detailList=this.scroll.childNodes[0];
    this.scrollHeight = this.scroll.clientHeight
}

handleScroll=()=>{
    if (this.scroll.scrollTop>this.maxScrollTop){
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat(this.getItems()),
        });
    }
}

handleDetailListUpdate=()=>{
    this.maxScrollTop=this.detailList.clientHeight-this.scrollHeight-100;
}

render(){

    let {
        items,
        selectionDetails
    } = this.state;

    return (
        <div
            style={{height:'800px', overflow:'auto' }}
            onScroll={this.handleScroll}
            ref={el => this.scroll = el}>
                <MarqueeSelection selection={ this._selection }>
                    <DetailsList
                        onDidUpdate={this.handleDetailListUpdate}
                    />
                </MarqueeSelection>
            </div>
    );
}

_getSelectionDetails = () => {
    let selectionCount = this._selection.getSelectedCount();
    switch (selectionCount) {
        case 0:
            return 'No items selected';
        default:
            return `${selectionCount} items selected`;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: огромное спасибо!